# Enumeration within self defined environment

Tags: environments, enumerate

My self defined environment having a symbol at the beginning and at the end works fine for text without enumeration. When including enumerate the symbols are not there where desired. Is it possible to have the first symbol directly in front of "1." i. e. in the same line and the ending symbol in the same line as the last line of the enumeration? With `\ignorespacesafterend` and `\unskip` I did not succeed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newenvironment{myenv}{$\blacktriangleright$}{\hfill$\blacktriangleleft$}

\begin{document}
There is a text.

\begin{myenv}
And an example
\end{myenv}

Here is another text.

\begin{myenv}
\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of nesting an `enumerate` environment inside a `myenv` environment, you could define a new list environment with `enumitem`, where the black triangles would be placed automatically at the beginning and at the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newenvironment{myenv}{$\blacktriangleright$}{\hfill$\blacktriangleleft$}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\newcommand*{\placebtr}{%
    \item[]
        \hspace*{-\labelsep}%
        \hspace*{-\labelwidth}%
        $\blacktriangleright$%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
    \vspace*{-\itemsep}%
    \vspace*{-\parsep}%
}
\setlist[myenumerate]{
    label=\arabic*.,
    first=\placebtr,
    after=\hfill$\blacktriangleleft$
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
There is a text.

\begin{myenv}
And an example
\end{myenv}

Here is another text.

\begin{myenumerate}
\item A
\item B
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With your code I get "Package enumitem Error: first undefined." Besides this: In your screenshot the triangle in front of the enumeration is indented less than the one before "An example"

Comment: @ubuntuuser I guess the error you get from `enumitem` means that you have an old version of the package, if you update it everything should work fine. For the indentation, thank you for pointing it out, I had made a mistake with the lengths used. I edited my answer and both triangles are aligned correctly.

Comment: @ubuntuuser I think I could clarify how triangles align on the left. In `myenumerate`, the triangle aligns directly on the left margin, but in `myenv`, the triangle is just placed at the start of the environment. For the triangle of `myenv` to align directly on the left margin as well when `myenv` is used at the start of a paragraph, I set `\parindent` to 0 in my answer. If you use a non-zero `\parindent`, be aware that the triangle of `myenv` will be indented by an amount of `\parindent` if it is at a start of a paragraph (unless you modify `myenv` or add `\noindent` or something like that).