# Go to last line of enumeration

Tags: enumerate, vspace

When adding afterwards a character to a enumeration I do not succeed by going back with `\vspace`: The character C in the MWE is positioned too "high". Is there a possibility to achieve this? (I need to do this because I want to define an environment including enumerations with a symbol at the end.)

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
\item B
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}
\hfill C

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want is not clear. Should `C` be on the same line as `B`?

Comment: I don't think this is the easiest way to define an environment including enumerations with a symbol at the end. Is this more or less the same question as [your last one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570830/201628)? Do you need another solution?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, C should be on the same line as B.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, it's the same problem. I answered there to your suggestion.

Comment: @Teepeemm That question is also mine, I thought another formulation may help.

Comment: The enumerate environment adds space (see \endtrivlist).  IIRC, \unskip doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an environment that automatically adds “C” at the end of the last line or on the next line if there's no room, but keeping it right flush.

Restriction: no blank line before `\end{qenumerate}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{qenumerate}
 {\enumerate}{\finalsymbol\endenumerate}

\newcommand{\finalsymbol}{%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty50\hskip1em\null\nobreak
   \hfill\mbox{\normalfont C}% <--- or whatever you want
   \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}%

}

\begin{document}

\begin{qenumerate}
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{qenumerate}

\begin{qenumerate}
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text text text text text text text
      text text text text text text~aaaaaa
\end{qenumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply adjust the `\vspace` to any decimal number you want. You can also change the unit, for example, `\vspace{-0.5cm}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A...
\item B...
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-0.9\baselineskip} % change to anything you want
\hfill C

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This would work, but would involve a lot of trial and error for OP, and might even change with changing font sizes.  I don't think I would recommend this approach.